# How to use batch separator inside Begin Try Catch SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I'm trying to create the SQL Script which needs to revert all the schema changes made if the error comes under any single SQL query. However, I'm trying to join both table and procedure under the same .sql file to run and try catch the error if present. It is working when i only uses the table, but when i try to add the procedure, it has some issue so added GO to separate table and procedure. But I can't able to Combine Begin try with GO statement.

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY
        Create TABLE [dbo].[Persons_1](
                [PersonID] [int] NULL,
                [LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [City] [varchar](255) NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY] ;

            Create TABLE [dbo].[Persons_2](
                [PersonID] [int] NULL,
                [LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [City] [varchar](255) NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY] ;

            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AAAtest]
                AS  
                BEGIN  
                    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
                    -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
                    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
                    -- Select statements for procedure here  
                    Select * from Persons_1 ;

                END;

        COMMIT 

    END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK;
     THROW; -- Only if you want reraise an exception (to determine the reason of the exception)
 END CATCH
```

Comment: `GO` isn't a T-SQL statement.

Comment: Sorry!, I have modified it now. This was the one I have used.

Comment: What are you trying to do and why are you trying to use `GO`? That's a tool command used by SSMS and sqlcmd. It's no different than selecting some SQL code and running it.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I'm not the DBA, I'm just Server Admin need to automate some process. which needs to combine both table and procedure into same file and reverse everything if error comes.

Comment: As for why you can't use `BEGIN TRY` and `GO`, it's because `GO` is a *batch separator*. The tool (SSMS/sqlcmd) splits the text between `GO` commands and sends each part as a *single* batch to SQL Server for execution. If you put `GO` in the middle of a statement or code block you'll end up with an incomplete block. SQL Server never sees that `GO` command

Comment: This is an ill-advised approach. Although you can perform some DDL statements inside a transaction (like `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE PROCEDURE`), plenty can't. Even for those that can, some statements must be the only ones in a batch (`CREATE PROCEDURE`) and therefore require dynamic SQL in T-SQL (`begin transaction; exec ('create procedure blarggg as begin return end;'); rollback`). You cannot hope to wrap everything in `TRY ... CATCH` and roll it back cleanly this way. Consider using technology intended for this, like DACPACs, which verify changes are safe first before performing them.

Comment: @JeroenMostert is there any way to achieve these type, I need to run the schema changes and all needs to be reverted if an error happens at any point

Comment: @VigneshVignasivakara writing change scripts isn't that easy. What `all` are you going to revert? If you only had to create tables, you could just drop the database in case of errors. In most cases though you need to write scripts that handle modifications, eg adding new columns to existing tables, changing data, handling foreign keys between existing tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need go statements in a batch. What you can do is use an exec statement. I added a drop table and drop proc so the program can be rerun as much as you want:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION
    BEGIN TRY

        DROP TABLE IF EXISTS  [dbo].[Persons_1] ;

        Create TABLE [dbo].[Persons_1](
                [PersonID] [int] NULL,
                [LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [City] [varchar](255) NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY] ;

           DROP TABLE IF EXISTS DBO.PERSONS_2;

            Create TABLE [dbo].[Persons_2](
                [PersonID] [int] NULL,
                [LastName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [FirstName] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [Address] [varchar](255) NULL,
                [City] [varchar](255) NULL
            ) ON [PRIMARY] ;

           DROP PROC IF EXISTS DBO.AAATEST;

DECLARE @TSQL VARCHAR(4000);
SET @TSQL = '
            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[AAAtest]
                AS  
                BEGIN  
                    -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from  
                    -- interfering with SELECT statements.  
                    SET NOCOUNT ON;  
                    -- Select statements for procedure here  
                    Select * from Persons_1 ;

                END;'
EXEC (@TSQL);


        COMMIT 

    END TRY
 BEGIN CATCH
     ROLLBACK;
     THROW; -- Only if you want reraise an exception (to determine the reason of the exception)
 END CATCH
```

Comment: This is a 2016 feature and I tested it before I posted the code.https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlserverstorageengine/2015/11/03/drop-if-exists-new-thing-in-sql-server-2016/

Comment: I stand corrected. Must have missed they added that in 2016.

Comment: Praise from Caeser is praise indeed.

Comment: Although `DROP IF EXISTS` works, I recommend going the opposite way: `IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM sys.sql_modules WHERE name = ...) EXEC ('CREATE PROCEDURE ... AS BEGIN RETURN END')` followed by an unconditional `ALTER`. This will preserve any existing `GRANT`ed permissions (which will be wiped out if you do a drop followed by a create). It also ensures that a failure to change the procedure will not affect anything, even without a transaction. Last but not least, it plays nice with auditing and replication. (Dropping tables is even more iffy, of course.)

Comment: @JeroenMostert understood, but I won't drop any table, because we will have huge data in it. I will just modify the table column datatypes only. So I'll use the Alter instead.

Comment: The code you had was create table.. But no problem.